# Running external program (Siesta) by java

Tags: java, linux, dft, siesta

I've checked many threads about running external programs but they cant solve my problem. 
for running Siesta (DFT Calculation) I have to use something like this (Si.fdf is the input file):
siesta < Si.fdf 
I'm using this code:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {

Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p;     
BufferedReader is; 
String line;

System.out.println("siesta < Si.fdf");
p = r.exec("siesta < Si.fdf");

System.out.println("In Main after exec");
is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((line = is.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(line);

System.out.println("In Main after EOF");
System.out.flush();
try {
  p.waitFor();  
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  System.err.println(e);  // 
  return;
}
System.err.println("Process done, exit status was " + p.exitValue());
return;
```

}

but this code only runs Siesta without any input file.

Comment: You are reading the `stdout` of the child process via `p.getInputStream()`.  You need to feed your data into the `stdin` of the child process via `p.getOutputStream()`.  Adding `< Si.fdf` to your `Runtime.exec()` parameter won't do what you want.

Comment: I've used the    
    OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
    out.write("< Si.fdf".getBytes());
    out.close();
But the " < Si.fdf" was sent after running Siesta not as a argument for running it.

Comment: I meant that you should write the **contents** of your input file into the `stdin` of your child process.  You solved your problem by having Bash do that work for you; Bash understands the character `<` as an instruction to read the input file and write its contents to `stdin` of Siesta.  Java does not interpret the `<` character like that, it is not a Unix shell.  To achieve the same thing in Java, you must recreate what Bash does: read the contents of the input file, and push those into the `stdin` of your child process.

Comment: Thanks. Finally it worked. I used your advice and used    final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("siesta");
   OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
   out.write(fileContents.getBytes());
   out.close();
and completly worked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've solve this. I add a batch file to terminal that the program control it's contents. By running this batch file the problem solved.

```
    public static void writeBatchFile(String batchFileName, String fileName, String inputFile) throws Exception{
    FileWriter write = new FileWriter(batchFileName);
    PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter(write);
    print_line.println("#!/bin/bash");
    print_line.println("siesta < "+ inputFile +".fdf"+ " > " +  fileName + ".out");
    print_line.close();
}
```